# need to save child without retrieve it in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to save the child table values without retrieve the values.

POJO Class:

```
 public class User {

private String firstName;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "userID", sequenceName = "userID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "userID")
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

private String lastName;


private Integer passwordReset;

@Column(name = "useremail", nullable = false, unique = true)
@Email
@NotEmpty
private String email;
@Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
private String password;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private List<WashingOrder> orderList;

@Column(unique = true)
@NotEmpty(message = "{username}")
private String username;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}


public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public Integer getPasswordReset() {
    return passwordReset;
}

public void setPasswordReset(Integer passwordReset) {
    this.passwordReset = passwordReset;
}

public List<WashingOrder> getOrderList() {
    return orderList;
}

public void setOrderList(List<WashingOrder> orderList) {
    this.orderList = orderList;
}


}



 public class WashingOrder {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "orderNo", sequenceName = "orderNo")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "orderNo")
@Column(name = "orderNo")
private Long orderNo;

@Column(name = "totalClothes", nullable = false)
@NotNull
private Integer totalClothes;

@Column(name = "mensCloth", nullable = true)
private Integer mensCloth;

@Column(name = "womensCloth", nullable = true)
private Integer womensCloth;

@Column(name = "otherCloth", nullable = true)
private Integer otherClothes;

@Column(name = "deliveryDate", nullable = true)
/* @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd") */
private Date deliveryDate;

@Column(name = "status", nullable = true)
private String orderStatus;

public Long getOrderNo() {
    return orderNo;
}

public void setOrderNo(Long orderNo) {
    this.orderNo = orderNo;
}

public Integer getTotalClothes() {
    return totalClothes;
}

public void setTotalClothes(Integer totalClothes) {
    this.totalClothes = totalClothes;
}

public Integer getMensCloth() {
    return mensCloth;
}

public void setMensCloth(Integer mensCloth) {
    this.mensCloth = mensCloth;
}

public Integer getWomensCloth() {
    return womensCloth;
}

public void setWomensCloth(Integer womensCloth) {
    this.womensCloth = womensCloth;
}

public Integer getOtherClothes() {
    return otherClothes;
}

public void setOtherClothes(Integer otherClothes) {
    this.otherClothes = otherClothes;
}

public Date getDeliveryDate() {
    return deliveryDate;
}

public void setDeliveryDate(Date deliveryDate) {
    this.deliveryDate = deliveryDate;
}

public String getOrderStatus() {
    return orderStatus;
}

public void setOrderStatus(String orderStatus) {
    this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
}
```

}

Implementation:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    long id = 1;
    Query query = session.createQuery("from user where id =" + id);
    User emp6 = (User) session.load(User.class, new Long(1));
    User user = (User) query.uniqueResult();
    List<WashingOrder> washingOrder = user.getOrderList();
    washingOrder.add(order);
    user.setOrderList(washingOrder);
    session.save(user);

    Long orderID = (long) 1;
    return orderID;
```

Here if you check I am getting the order list first (user.getOrderList()) and then I am adding the new list and saving the user.

But I want to save the new order list of the user without retrieve the previous order list.

There is any possibility for the adding new order data without retrieve the previous order list of the particular user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change a mapping

```
public class User {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<WashingOrder> orderList;

}

public class WashingOrder {

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   private User user;

}


Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
User user = (User) session.load(User.class, 1L);
WashingOrder order = new WashingOrder();
order.setUser(user);
session.save(order);
```

You can try to use a fake `User` instead of loading

```
WashingOrder order = new WashingOrder();
order.setUser(new User(1L));
session.save(order);
```